# Is it possible to add a kill button to the window frame?

Tags: window, kill, button

It would be very handy many times to have a kill button somewhere around the Close, Minimize and the Maximize buttons.
Is it possible somehow or maybe there is a quicker way to kill an unresponsive process?

Comment: How about a keyboard shortcut for `xkill`?

Comment: Or in Ubuntu with Unity, simply press Alt+F2 and enter the `xkill` command there. When you open that panel again the next time, it will remember the previous commands as clickable buttons.

Comment: Ok, I got a solution which is not exactly the answer for the question, but it is better idea. Should I delete the post or what?

Comment: Common practice is to ask the commenter to make an answer containing their comment and then mark that comment as the answer. If you delete we lose this and future searchers have to ask again.